# PHP script doesn't run when called by lookup in $PATH variable

Tags: bash, php

I have a PHP script located in a folder in my $PATH variable. The first line of the script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

When I execute this script in bash by supplying the path to the script (for example)

```
$ ./mattPWDtrim
$ bin/scripts/mattPWDtrim
```

Or execute it using the PHP CLI program:

```
$ php mattPWDtrim
$ php bin/mattPWDtrim
$ php -f mattPWDtrim
```

The script runs normally with the expected output.
It also runs fine if I do the following:

```
$ `which mattPWDtrim`
```

However, if I try and run the script without the PHP CLI program, and without specifying a path to the script, the script simply doesn't run.

Does anyone know why?

EDIT: This is the invocation that fails:

```
$ mattPWD_truncate
```

It doesn't matter if I'm in the same folder as the script, or anywhere else on my system.

Comment: The output of "which php" is "/usr/bin/php" without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

PHP shell scripts still have to have a `<?php` in them to enable "PHP mode". e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
echo 'foo'
```

output is `echo 'foo'`

v.s.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'foo'
```

output is `foo`

Remember, there's no such thing as a "php script". There's just files which have `<?php ... ?>` PHP code blocks within them. Without `<?php` to enable PHP mode, the file's contents will simply be treated as plain output.

Comment: The 2nd line of my script is "<?php" and the last line of my script is "?>". This is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just read this comment:

> I would suggest to use “#!/usr/bin/env php” instead of a hard-coded
>   path to php, as this allows for the php binary to be anywhere in the
>   user’s PATH.

On this page: http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2007/04/24/tips-and-tricks-php-shell-scripts/

Perhaps this will fix your issue.